# Eigen crash due to unaligned access with MSVC14 and AVX

Tags: visual-studio, crash, alignment, eigen, avx

I have a following piece of code that can take advantage of SIMD. It works fine on Linux + GCC but I have been banging my head against a wall for a while now because it crashes when I build it with MSVC with AVX enabled.

```
template <>
void NewtonRaphson<double, InstructionSet::AVX>::initializeLu(const int elements)
{
    std::cerr << "EDE " << EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Allocations are already aligned = " << EIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED << "\n";

    m_luCalc = new Eigen::PartialPivLU<SolverMatrix<double>>(elements);
}

template <>
typename NewtonRaphson<double, InstructionSet::AVX>::TX const & NewtonRaphson<double, InstructionSet::FMA3>::ASolve()
{
    m_iteration = 0;
    m_stuckCounter = 0;

    AInit();

    // DOIT

    std::cerr << "EDE WKR" << EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES << "\n";
    std::cerr << "...WKR Allocations are already aligned = " << EIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED << "\n";

    while (true)
    {
        // !2
        ACalculateF(m_f, *m_px);
        ACalculateJ(m_j, *m_px);

        ZCalculateMeasures(m_f, m_fMin, m_fMax);
        ZCalculateMeasures(m_dx, m_dxMin, m_dxMax);                                  // 1

        ZCheckStatus();

        if (m_status != Status::CONTINUE)
            return *m_px;

        this->m_iteration++;

        m_luCalc->compute(m_j);
        m_dx = m_luCalc->solve(m_f);

        *m_px -= m_dx;
    };

    return *m_px;
}
```

The code resides in a separate .cpp file which is compiled with appropriate optimization flags set. The crash occurs at the beginning of the PartialPivLU::compute() function. A quick look at the assembly generated by MSVC for the offending function reveals this:

```
5D43D243  jle         Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> >::compute<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,32,Eigen::Stride<0,0> > >+0E9h (5D43D269h)  
5D43D245  nop         word ptr [eax+eax]  
5D43D250  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]  
5D43D253  vmovupd     ymm0,ymmword ptr [eax+ecx*8]  
5D43D258  vmovapd     ymmword ptr [edi+ecx*8],ymm0
```

The crash happens at the `vmovapd` instruction which tries to read form a 16-byte aligned address. EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES is set to 32 and EIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED is 0. This code works OK when I tune the SIMD optimizations down to SSE2.

Is there anything I am missing to achieve proper alignment with MSVC?

Comment: Are you sure all cpp files are compiled with exact same flags??

Comment: Also, it seems that `m_j` is a `Map<MatrixXd,32>` meaning that you allocated yourself the coefficients of `m_j` and you're telling Eigen that the buffer you passed is 32bytes aligned. Are you sure of that? Have you tried in "debug" mode to see whether you get some useful assertions?

Comment: @ggael I checked what the valued of `m_data` pointers in `m_j` and `m_lu` are and  `m_j` is allocated properly to 32 bytes. The `m_lu` which is auto-allocated by Eigen is not and the code crashes when it tries to do aligned access into `m_lu`. At this point I am suspecing Eigen's `handmade_aligned_malloc()` doing something funky. All assertions seem to go through fine so as far as Eigen itself is concerned there is nothing wrong.

Comment: You mean the `m_lu` member of `PartialPivLU`? What is `SolverMatrix<double>`? It seems to be a `MatrixXd`. Can you test if assigning `Map<MatrixXd,32>` to `MatrixXd` works reliably? Also make sure that you are on the most recent repository version of Eigen.

Comment: ©chtz - Yes, the one in PartialPivLU. `SolverMatrix<double>` is just a library-agnostic synonym to `MatrixXd`. I did some more digging and as far as I can tell the `EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES` that actually propagates to Eigen's allocator is set to 16 even though the cerr just above the constructor call returns 32. When I force-feed the 32 byte alignment to Eigen's `Memory.h` the core runs. Weird... I am on eigen 3.3.4 as that seems to be the latest stable release.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I have gotten to the bottom of this. My code detects what CPU instruction sets are available at runtime and dynamically dispatches execution to functions that make use of the available instruction sets. I moved parts of my code that utilize different SIMD instructions to different TUs to make this possible. This works okay until I decided to switch on vectorization in parts of code that use Eigen directly. Although every TU reincludes all of Eigen again so its internal values are set accordingly, Eigen's allocators are not templated and defined as inline. The compiler therefore merges all definitions of `handmade_aligned_malloc` into just one function even though they don't actually do the same thing because the value of EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES is different in each TU based on what compiler flags are set. The fact that it works with GCC under Linux is probably accidental. Although I still have to figure out a proper fix for this I believe this answers the question of what was causing the crash.

Comment: You can compile every TU with `-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=32` to have everything (with size>16bytes) always aligned to 32 bytes

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Apparently there is no easy way out once the internal storages get allocated with wrong alignment.